# Analytic function, $\text{ Im} f(e^{i\theta}) = \sin\theta $

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations

> Suppose that $ f(z) $ is analytic in $ |z| < 10 $ and $ \text{ Im}f(e^{i\theta})=\sin\theta $, for $ \theta \in \mathbb{R} $. Find $ f $ in $ |z| < 10 $ and justify your answer.

---

I denoted $ f(z) = f(x + iy) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$. Parameterization of a unit circle is $ x(\theta) = \cos\theta $, $ y(\theta) = \sin\theta $, therefore $ Imf(\theta) = v(\cos\theta, \sin\theta) = \sin\theta$.

\begin{equation}
\frac{dv}{d\theta}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d\theta} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{d\theta} = \cos\theta\\
\end{equation}
Given that $ v $ is harmonic, we have
\begin{equation}
x(\theta) = \cos\theta\\
y(\theta) = \sin\theta\\
-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\sin\theta + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\cos\theta = \cos\theta\\
\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} = 0,
\end{equation}
which is not that easy to solve. Or, equivalently, in polar coordinates:

\begin{equation}
v(1, \theta) = \sin\theta\\
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial \theta^2} = 0
\end{equation}

Another possible approach I thought of is considering $ f(z) = z $, which satisfies the initial conditions, and proving that such function is unique. It should have something to do with the uniqueness theorem, but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: It's not $f(z) = e^z$. Note $e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, so you have $\operatorname{Im} (f(z) - z) \equiv 0$ on $\lvert z\rvert = 1$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I meant to say $ f(z) = z $

Comment: Note that $f$ is _not_ uniquely determined by the given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set $\displaystyle \Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Then $\Omega$ is open and bounded, hence if $v(x,y)$ is harmonic in $\Omega$ and we know $v(x,y)$ on $\partial\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$, the solution is unique. We do have this information, so since $v(x,y)=y$ satisfies the conditions, this is the solution. Then using the Cauchy-Riemann equations, this gives $f(z)=z+c$ in $\Omega$ where $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $f(z)$ is analytic inside $|z|<10$, we have $f(z)=z+c$ inside $|z|<10$.

Comment: Not entirely right, we can add an arbitrary real constant.

Comment: Fixed. Forgive me.

Comment: Read ten pages of Euler to your neighbours, and forgiveness is yours.